# OpenGL & Stellarium in Ubuntu 16.04 32 bits

Tags: 16.04, qt, opengl

I have installed Stellarium 0.14.3-1 in my Ubuntu 16.04. When I run it, I get the next message:

```
No OpenGL 2 found on this system.
Please upgrade hardware or use MESA or an older version.
```

I think it is related with the graphics drivers. I downloaded an older version of Stellarium (first 0.12 and then 0.10) but when I configured them with `cmake` according with [this](http://stellarium.org/wiki/index.php/Compilation_on_Linux), I get

```
Found unsuitable Qt version " " from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
```

What can I do to make Stellarium work?

Just in case it is useful for you, I copy the data given by `glxinfo`:

```
jorge@jorge-netbook:~$ glxinfo
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info,
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig,
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float,
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info,
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Pineview M x86/MMX/SSE2 (0xa011)
    Version: 11.2.0
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 384MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: compat (0x2)
    Max core profile version: 0.0
    Max compat profile version: 1.4
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 2.0
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Pineview M x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax,
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5,
    GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels,
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility,
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage,
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_texture,
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex,
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location,
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_shader,
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_get_program_binary,
    GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel,
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata,
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind,
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object,
    GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite,
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex,
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects,
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shadow,
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_compression,
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat,
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle,
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix,
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding,
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader,
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_draw_buffers,
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_EXT_abgr,
    GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate,
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract,
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_copy_texture,
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters,
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil,
    GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_point_parameters,
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal,
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color,
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap,
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc,
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic,
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle,
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_vertex_array,
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip,
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate,
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, GL_MESA_pack_invert,
    GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, GL_NV_blend_square,
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil,
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4,
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_read_format,
    GL_S3_s3tc, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp,
    GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays   
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5,
    GL_APPLE_texture_max_level, GL_EXT_blend_minmax,
    GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer, GL_EXT_draw_buffers,
    GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_EXT_map_buffer_range,
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_read_format_bgra,
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1,
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888,
    GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV, GL_EXT_unpack_subimage,
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, GL_NV_draw_buffers,
    GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments, GL_NV_read_buffer, GL_NV_read_depth,
    GL_NV_read_depth_stencil, GL_NV_read_stencil, GL_OES_EGL_image,
    GL_OES_EGL_sync, GL_OES_depth24, GL_OES_depth_texture,
    GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_OES_element_index_uint,
    GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_mapbuffer,
    GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil, GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, GL_OES_stencil8,
    GL_OES_surfaceless_context, GL_OES_texture_3D, GL_OES_texture_npot,
    GL_OES_vertex_array_object
```

```
12 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x020 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x021 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x074 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x075 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x076 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x077 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x078 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x079 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x07a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x07b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x07c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x05b 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
```

```
24 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x05c  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x05d  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x05e  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x05f  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x060 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x061 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x062 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x063 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x064  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x065  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16 0  0 0 Slow
0x066 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x067 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x068  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x069  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x06a  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x06b  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x06c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x06d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x06e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x06f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x070  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x071  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16 0  0 0 Slow
0x072 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0 0  0 0 None
0x073 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions:

1.- Run `Stellarium` with `gallium llvmpipe software render`:

```
 LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 stellarium
```

It works but it's quite slow, but it is run.

2 - One installed the PPA https://launchpad.net/~oibaf said by @angry-penguin , just right click and choose "Open in diagnostic mode". In my case I preferred not use this because I got problems with my desktop theme.

No error messages are shown. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, your Mesa working fine? Do you trying any OpenGL games. Games run?

I see in output this:

```
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 11.2.0
```

So you have Mesa 11.2 and you only use OpenGL 1.4 if I correct understand.
So maybe you can try install PPA with new Mesa version? Try this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf

Answer (score -1):

Sony Vaio VGN-FS415s, Nvidia gforce go 6400, Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit. I got around this by downgrading Qt. Be aware this may have unexpected effects on other applications.

Newer stellarium doesn´t support my graphics card, older stellarium doesn´t support Qt5. So I chose to install an old version and downgrade to Qt4.

- I downloaded the original nvidia legacy driver for my card  (304.135 32 bits) from [the nvidia site here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html). The 304 driver from Ubuntu repo didn´t work on high resolution.
- The nvdia file has to be executed from terminal outside X with

  ```
  sudo sh <nvidia_file.run>
  ```
- I downloaded stellarium-0.12.5.tar.gz from [here on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/stellarium/0.12)
  and compiled  with

  ```
  cmake /path/to/the/extracted/stellarium/file
  ```
- Installed Qt4

  ```
  sudo apt install qt4
  ```
- Uninstalled Qt5, I did

  ```
  sudo apt autoremove qt5
  ```
- rebooted.

Now stellarium is showing a beautiful crystal clear sky.

Comment: What in the world are you saying? I am clueless...